# Get element from external XML page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, get, external

So I'm not that great with javascript, but I'm trying to make a mail notification or this sort of things.

So far I'm using gmails xml file that will display the number of unread emails under a fullcount tag. I want to fetch this with javascript and display it on a html page. Is there a better way to do this?

So far I've come up with this:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="gmail.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload=getgmail();>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="gmail">
                <p id="mail">0</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function getgmail() {

    //loadpage
    $.get("https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom", function(data));

    //get variable inside fullcount tags
    var mailcount= document.getElementsByTagName('fullcount');

    //output variable to html
    document.getElementById('mail').innerHTML = fullcount;

}
```

I'm probably doing it completely wrong and I would appreciate your help! thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
function getgmail() {

    $.get("https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom", function(data) {
        var mailcount = data.getElementsByTagName("fullcount")[0].textContent;
        document.getElementById('mail').innerHTML = mailcount;
    );

}
```

You should check out [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) API documentation.